# EmberJS: How to make a helper that can return data from a promise

Tags: ember.js

I created a `{{findby}}` helper that is super useful for picking an item out of an array, but i ran into a problem.  The helper does not like to call `findBy()` on an array which is a promiseArray.

So the helper was modified to do this:

```
export function findby([array, key, value]) {
  let isPromiseArray = Ember.typeOf(array.then) === 'function';
  if (isPromiseArray) {
    array.then((arr) => {
      return arr.findBy(key, value) || null;
    });
  } else {
    return array.findBy(key, value) || null;
  }
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(findby);
```

the idea being of course, if a passed array happens to be a PromiseArray, use a `then()` before trying to call `findBy()`.

The problem is that I cant seem to return anything in this case.. returning from inside the `then()` does not seem to actually close out the helper function so the helper returns undefined.

If i try to do:

```
return array.then((arr) => {
  return arr.findBy(key, value) || null;
});
```

then just the promise itself gets returned from the helper.

Here is a twiddle of what I have attempted: https://ember-twiddle.com/c82fb0e11641703f118e867b45403654?numColumns=2&openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Chelpers.findby.js

THe question seems to be a general one for helpers:  Is there a way to return data from a promise/then() function in a helper? I wonder if what i want to do is even possible with a helper?

Comment: You should check out [ember-promise-helpers](https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-promise-helpers)

Comment: @nem ok thanks, that does seem like it can be useful!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just should call `recompute`!

So something like this:

```
function findBy([array, key, value]) {
    let content = Ember.get(array, 'content');

    if(!content) {
        array.then(() => this.recompute());
        return null;
    }

    return content.findBy(key, value) || null;
}
```

What you tried is not possible. If you write return `.then(() => <here>);`, you return the arrow function not the parent function. The parent function returned long before and well, it will not even wait for promises.

But you can always call `.recompute` to well, recompute, and this will work for you.

Comment: that looks like a good idea.. i saw code similar to that looking at the promise-helper addon.. but.. can I call `recompute` on a normal helper function? or does it need to be a class based helper?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think ember data wraps your function in a helper instance. So it should work. But try it.